# Combining functions that satisfy the Inada conditions

Tags: macroeconomics, production-function

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions that satisfy the [Inada conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inada_conditions), and also
$$
\forall i:
\lim_{x_i \to \infty} h(\mathbf{x}) = \infty.
$$

Does the function $f(h(\mathbf{x}))$ also satisfy the conditions?

Comment: For $n=1$ and $g(x)\equiv f(h(x))$ we have that $g'(x)=f'(h(x))h'(x)$. I therefore guess that whether $\lim_{x\to\infty}g'(x)$ is 0 or not depends on $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)$ and the functional forms. My intuition is that there is a counterexample.

Comment: @Elias I guess not having $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \infty$ is an issue. If you have that all the others seem to follow.

Comment: The condition of the unbounded derivative when $x$ approaches infinity seems to contradict the Inada conditions. According to your link, the derivative should converge to zero. Despite this, I don't think the result follows mainly because convexity is not preserved under composition, for example, $g(x)=-x^2$ and $f(x)=-e^{x}$ are both concave, but $f(g(x))$ is not concave. Granted $g(x)$ does not satisfy the Inada conditions, but I'm sure a counterexample exists.

Comment: Convexity is preserved under composition if the function that serves as an argument of the other is monotonically increasing. From @Elias's comment, it seems that assuming  $h(x)$ strictly increasing and unbounded will give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: @Regio Composition not preserving convexity does indeed seem problematic. Though the other conditions imply a sort of strictly increasing concavity, which your function $g$ is not. And indeed, over $\mathbb{R}_+$ where $g$ is strictly increasing even the composition is strictly concave. This may be a special case though. If you were to come up with a counter example, it would answer the question and I would happily upvote it. EDIT: seems like we crossposted the same thought.

Comment: "*if the function that serves as an argument of the other is monotonically increasing*." This is implied by the second Inada condition, is it not?

Comment: You are right. It is implied. I don't think you answered my first concern, did you mean to add the condition $\lim_{x_i\rightarrow\infty}h(x_i)=\infty$ for all $i$? Otherwise, the condition you currently have is contradicting the 4th condition for Inada, or am  I missing something?

Comment: @Regio Oops! Yes, that is a mistake. Thank you for catching it!

Comment: I don't see why you need the extra condition $ \forall i:
\lim_{x_i \to \infty} h(\mathbf{x}) = \infty $. To revisit Elias' example ($n = 1$), we know that the derivative of the composed function is $f'(h(x))h'(x)$. Since $h$ satisfies the Inada conditions, $h'(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Moreover, it is *not* true that $f'(h(x)) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$: this would require that $h(x) \rightarrow 0$, which is false. Thus, the derivative of the composed function converges to 0 (without needing the condition).

Comment: @afreelunch The general argument as to why $f'$ is bounded over this particular range seems more complicated to me, but I think you are right in gist. Type up an answer for the general $(n \geq 1)$ case?